# Trajectory Rollout paper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

On the wiki page for base_local_planner, there's a link [link](http://pub1.willowgarage.com/apubdb_html/files_upload/8.pdf) to a paper discussing TR. The link's broken; can anyone point me to a copy of this paper?

Thanks,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190486/trajectory-rollout-paper/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CiteSeerX seems to have a cached copy available for download: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.330.2120

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-08-18**:
Ok, now I feel *really* dumb: I had actually found that page but didn't notice the "cached" link. Thanks!